# Best practice: Generic interfaces

Tags: c#

I have made an generic interface like:

```
public interface IDatabaseElement<T>
{
  IList<T> GetAll();
  T Get(id);
  void Save(T element);
  void Delete(int id);
}
```

If I have e.g. two elements (Person and Store) which uses only the above methods what is then considered best practice?

A: Making a new interface for each element like:

```
public interface IPerson : IDatabaseElement<Person> { }
public interface IStore : IDatabaseElement<Store> { }
```

and then my classes like:

```
public class Person : IPerson { .... }
public class Store : IStore { .... }
```

and when instanciating variables:

```
IPerson person = new Person();
IStore store = new Store();
```

or
B: using the generic interfaces directly like:

```
public class Person : IDatabaseElement<Person> { .... }
public class Store : IDatabaseElement<Store> { .... }
```

and when instainciating variables:

```
IDatabaseElement<Person> person = new Person();
IDatabaseElement<Store> store = new Store();
```

What is considered best practice?

Comment: this question is off topic.

Comment: @olf Do take a look at the FAQs of SO, the question is not about a specific problem.

Comment: Why do your entities know about databases in the first place? And your methods are completely nonsensical for an entity, they'd fit a repository.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a known design pattern for what you are calling `IDatabaseElement<T>`; it is called the [Repository Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html). So start by renaming `IDatabaseElement<T>` to:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> { ... }
```

Furthermore, since you define the `IPerson` interface, it seems like you are defining an interface for the `Person` entity, instead of the repository.

Hiding your entity behind an interface is bad practice because your entities are data objects and interfaces are only needed to abstract behavior.

So instead of calling the interface `IPerson`, start by calling it `IPersonRepository`.

On the other hand, if your `Person` class actually contains data (such as `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Age`, etc), in that case you are mixing responsibilities. Your entities should not know how to retrieve themselves  (or other instances!!!) from the database. Retrieving data from the database and holding the data are two different responsibilities and you should separate them (give each responsibility its own class). Your system will very soon become unmaintainable if you violate the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Now, making a specific interface for each repository type (such as `IPersonRepository`) is a bad idea. The main reason for having a generic abstraction is because this makes adding extra behavior (such as crosscutting concerns) much easier, because this allows you to define a single generic decorator, for instance: `AuditTrailingRepositoryDecorator<T>`. But when you let your person repository implementation inherit from `IPersonRepository`, you can't wrap it with a generic decorator anymore, simply because all methods you defined on `IPersonRepository` itself will not be accessible anymore. This also makes it much easier to write unit tests, since in your test suite you will only have to create one single generic fake implementation of `IRepository<T>`.

If you're not interested in adding crosscutting concerns and the ability to easily test your code base, you can go with the specific (non generic) interfaces such as `IPersonRepository` and `IStoreRepository`.